# viewing primary keys as text in tables

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am wondering when one has a DB with relationship linked tables, with each table having its own primary key field, is it possible when looking at the table to have the primary key data show up as text as opposed to the primary key number?

On the forms this is not an issue, but the request I received was to have the option to look at the tables themselves and see all the data as text.  I know this is a big no-no going to the tables directly instead of working through the forms, but that is the request so I’m trying to figure out if this is possible.
An example would be the following:

On one table called boats, each boat would have its own unique identifying number (primary key number).  Concurrently on another table called owners each owner would have its own unique identifier (primary key number).

So if one is looking at the boats table they would see the owner represent as the number in the linked owner field.  In this instance the boat’s owner is Bob, and Bob happens to be in the owner table as the first entry, so Bob has the unique identifier number of 1.  When I look at the table I see all the information about the boat in text, but when I look at the owner field I see the number 1 instead of seeing the text ‘Bob’.

I realize the issue may be that the linked fields must both be of a numeric type, which they are, and this would create the situation where the table data is presented as numeric.   If the table relationship is successful, which I believe it is, is there a setting to see the primary key as text?

If not, can anyone offer an explanation as to why this is not possible.   This is the same DB I’ve written about in other posts, so hopefully this is the last issue I will be having with it.  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should never use tables to present data to you users.

Tables are for storing data - not interacting with it. It is far too easy to delete data and put non conforming values directly into a table.

So quite simple answer really. Use a form.

Answer (score 1):

Minty is correct.  My only additional recommendation is using the datasheet form view.  Then you can use a combo box to display the key values as text, and it will give users the illusion of working directly in the tables as you desire.  I was playing around with it a bit and apparently the forms won't open in datasheet view even if that's the only option.  But you can set an on open event to open the form in datasheet view.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I'll try it out.  I agree, and I put in the initial post I know it is not a good idea to allow access to the tables, but I am out ranked on this request so I must see what I can do.  Thanks for this.

Comment: In order to get the "Higher powers" to see why you don't let them at tables, simply demonstrate the time and effort required to reload a backup when someone makes that mistake of deleting a months worth of invoices or sales leads. I bet you a small lottery win, you can't get to the tables in your off the shelf accounts package in the application. For a very good reason.

Comment: Set the `DefaultView` property to make the form open in Datasheet view.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's definitely easier than the on open event.

Comment: I am finding now there must be a bigger problem.  On the forms what was once represented as text is starting to show up as numeric.  When one looks at the tables the numbers (primary keys) correspond correctly, but the number does not give the end user much to work with, unless they open up the table and check they are working with the correct record.  Not sure why this is happening, or what the bigger issue is.  Started with one recorded converting from text to number on the form and is now showing up on other records ???

Comment: Well it's time to troubleshoot.  Make sure the combo box is working correctly and you have the correct fields selected for display.  If you have the issue surrounded but can't figure it out, feel free to post another question.